# Creating standalone app with Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

Once I saw a DB made in MS Access that worked as a normal program, i.e with an executable file that opened a beautiful UI and allowed access to the forms and reports. I've trying to do the same, I even googled but didn't find how do it. Anyone knows how to build such standalone App with Access?

Comment: Don't you prefer a beautiful web app that uses a beautiful server based database system?

Comment: Personally I prefer the application that gets the job done within the time allowed and gives the features the client wants. If that’s a web app then great, if that’s a thick client then that’s also great. Also don’t forget that access can be used as a front end to many server based RDMSs

Comment: did you see a program working on an Access DB (that means: Access as the backend), or did you see a program created with Access as the frontend? If the 2nd case is what you are talking of: what makes you sure the application was created with Access?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cant make an access database into an executable file. It just cant happen however you can fool people into thinking that they are not using access a number of ways, for example

- Custom splash screen (just put a bmp
  file in the folder and name it the
  same as your database)
- Hide the access window and toolbars
- Change the access icon

For example take a look at this screen shot

[image]

There are lots of things going on here and it would be hard to tell that it is built using good old access 97 (Yes I know the standard toolbar kind of gives it away, it will be going at somepoint).

Comment: That's a nice-looking UI.  Access gets a bad rap because it is (ab)used by so many novice "developers."  In capable hands it is a phenomenal RAD tool.  It's not the hammer's fault a seamstress can't build a nice house.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the tool is called the Microsoft Access Runtime toolkit or something along those lines.  The latest version is free, a departure from the previous versions which I believe you had to pay for.  From the previous version I tinkered with, it comes with a tool to make a EXE file from the MDB or ACCB file, a handful of icons for the EXE to use if you are lacking one, and a program to help you generate Microsoft Help files for your application.

This is a link to the Developer Extensions - I believe the 2007 version of what I described above:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=D96A8358-ECE4-4BEE-A844-F81856DCEB67&displaylang=en

Here is a link for the runtime, which doesn't convert your Access database into an executable file, but would allow it to run on computers without Access installed:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=D9AE78D9-9DC6-4B38-9FA6-2C745A175AED&displaylang=en

NOTE:  Both of these are for Access 2007, the version I run.  Your version might require something different - but should be easily located on Microsoft's website.

Comment: Here's a link to current (2021) Microsoft access runtime: https://www.microsoft.com/el-gr/download/details.aspx?id=50040

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fool the user in thinking that they are not using access it will take some ingenuity. I have done this. You will need a way to make nice 2D images that you will import into access, and then set them up like buttons, and give them functionality. Make sure you over lay them on a splash screen of some kind. Not sure if you know VBA but it will be needed.

At the end make sure you go in to the setting, and turn off anything that might allow the user to alter the form in any way. And then rename the file's extension like this: fileName.accdr

This is as close to a normal program that you are going to get, and remember it will only look as good as the art you put into it.