# How to secure my program from "illegal" copying?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Last year I started to develop a small "program" (not sure how this is called) in Access to help the family shop with the stock list and product prices, etc.

A few months ago, a client of the company started to ask for my Access's program because he needed one for its stock and they haven't found one yet. I was a bit scared of giving them the program because they could copy and steal my work.

Finally, my family suggested me to encrypt it in order to not be able to open its code, but I don't know how to do it.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to block the access to my VBA code in each Form? Through MS Access config or with more code, for me, it's the same.
- Is there a way to block the duplication of its Forms or the whole file?

How can I secure my code?

I'm using MS Access 2016.

**Edit:** I've already got 2 downvotes and close flags, if you could explain to me in comments which thing do you think it's wrong I could try to fix it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179795/prevent-enabling-of-shift-bypass-access-2010 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/24638829/3820271

Comment: Why the downvote and the close flag? If you explain to me I can try to improve my question in order to fit your requirements.

Comment: I've just edited my question in order to make it less broad. I hopes this help.

Comment: About the Off-Topic vote, I disagree. I am not asking about a tool or a book. I'm rather asking if there is some code I could put in order to block my program from being read and copy. If that code could be instead replaced with a config of Access great, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: About the Too-Broad vote, why is too broad? It's just how to prevent my code from being open in Access with VBA or another thing.

Comment: I hate it when people downvote. It is like a drive by shooting. A person die without knowing the reason. If you downvote, please give a reason. (Of course, if the question is really strange, I can see the reason. This? I am not sure.)

Comment: This question is too broad in my opinion, because security and securing code is a very broad subject (which includes things like obfuscation and de-obfuscation, compilation, encryption, etc.) and you don't specify exactly what you want. I can't judge if any of the provided answers provide sufficient security for you, or if it's something else entirely that you want. That makes this question a bad fit for stack overflow. A question like _how do encrypt an accdb_ would be more narrow, for example.

Comment: I haven't (yet) contributed to the close or downvotes, but when you look at the one answer it basically links to outside information, rather than providing the information IN the answer. There's really too much information to do so which is an indication that the question is "too broad". Also, the information in the two answers is incomplete...

Comment: ... the topic would really need a tutorial or full discussion to cover all the aspects of *distributing* your solution effectively. For example, many Access developers *split* an Access solution: data in one database, forms, code in another. Then the customer has full access to their data, but the UI is yours, protected, and they have no access. This would then also be better for you as far as maintenance and distribution goes - you wouldn't have to worry about your data being in what you give to others. It's not just your code you need to worry about!

Comment: ...And the fact that I needed two comments to communicate this is yet another indication that the question is "too broad".

Comment: @EnderLook Have you created an ACCDE per the answer from SEarl1986?  Is that adequate or do you need something more?

Comment: @HansUp, yes, I've done it. I think it'll be adequate for my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access 2016 allows you to save as .accde format which is in effect an executable file. It seems that is what you need

[Heres's how](https://www.quackit.com/microsoft_access/microsoft_access_2016/tutorial/make_an_executable_database_in_microsoft_access.cfm)

you can also hide most of the Access environment so users can't really tell its Access

[like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440150/creating-standalone-app-with-microsoft-access)

Answer (score 1):

Saving as an executable file as SEarl1986 said may be your best bet.  I am unsure what happens to their database if you need to update your code tho.

Another way is to open Visual Basic, go to Tools, and "yourfilenames" properties, then under the protection tab you can "lock the project for viewing" and add a password.

It isn't foolproof as their is a method to break the password by editing the file with a hex editing tool, but it's a good lock that will deter most people.  It will protect your code from prying eyes.